# Why my simple code won't run even its simple and not mine

Tags: python, pycharm

The video is for coding an simle space invaser game (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crV6T3piwHQ) and i'm following everything but i'm on windows and he's on linux.
The first problem was that "import os" was not acceptable in python on windows but i found that the line "import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(**file**))
" will solve the problem. But when I laiinch the game nothing happens past the black screen, it's just lagging and I can shut the window unless I do it from pycharm.
Here's the code

```
import turtle
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# screen setup
# wn = screen object
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Space Invaders")


# borders
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300, -300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)

for side in range(4):
   border_pen.fd(600)
   border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

delay = input("Press enter to exit... ")
```

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: if you check the video, the code that you have written is supposed to do nothing other than drawing a border. If you are able to see a black screen with a white border then it is expected. If you notice closely, even in the video he doesn't close the turtle screen directly, instead he closes the terminal window from where he executed the script, which is the same as closing from pycharm...

Comment: @RazKissos I'm using python 3.8